# R purrr: Map accuracy to forecast object and return accuracy

Tags: r

I cannot figure out how to get accuracy metrics into a tibble from the forecast objects that are in the tibble. Here is a straight-forward example of 2 forecast objects returning accuracy():

```
# create 2 forecast objects
stl.fcast <- AirPassengers %>% stl(s.window="periodic") %>% forecast(h = 12)
ets.fcast <- AirPassengers %>% ets() %>% forecast(h = 12)

# now get the accuracy
accuracy(stl.fcast) # returns accuracy metrics on stl.fcast
accuracy(ets.fcast) # returns accuracy metrics on ets.fcast
```

[image]

Awesome. I got accuracy. Now I try to do the same thing using purr / dplyr methods, to loop over a number of models and store the results in a tibble.

```
models_list <- list(
  ets = list(y = AirPassengers), 
  stl = list(x = AirPassengers, t.window=NULL, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE))

models_tbl <- enframe(models_list, name = "f", value = "params") %>% 
  mutate(fit = invoke_map(f, params)) %>% 
  mutate(fcast = map(fit, forecast, h = 12))

models_tbl # print tibble
```

Great, my table has everything I need except for accuracy metrics

[image]

Now, when I try and create a new column containing accuracy for each forecast object in my table 'models_tbl', I get NULL.

```
models_tbl %>% 
transmute(acc = map(fcast, accuracy)) # RETURNS NULL
```

Returns -> A tibble: 2 x 1 ,  # should return 2 rows of accuracy.

How can I accomplish this? Ideally, I could parse these accuracy metrics out to many columns, so that I could easily compare all models by their accuracy metrics. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `accuracy` returns a 7-column matrix for each row in your tibble, it can be tricky to use a `mutate` (or `transmute`) statement to attach those columns to the tibble. If you'd like to have the 7 columns containing accuracy metrics added to your tibble, you could do something along the lines of:

```
library(magrittr)
models_tbl %$% 
  map(fcast, accuracy) %>% 
  plyr::ldply() %>% 
  cbind(models_tbl, .) %>% 
  as.tibble

# A tibble: 2 x 11
# f       params     fit       fcast           ME    RMSE  MAE    MPE   MAPE  MASE   ACF1
# <chr>   <list>     <list>    <list>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 ets   <list [1]> <S3: ets> <S3: forecast>  1.57   10.7  7.79  0.436  2.86 0.243 0.0395
# 2 stl   <list [4]> <S3: stl> <S3: forecast> -0.577  21.6 14.4  -0.395  5.18 0.451 0.226
```

The `%$%` operator used above pipes the sub-objects of a variable. So `models_tbl %$% map(fcast, accuracy)` is the same as `map(models_tbl$fcast, accuracy)`. Likewise, `table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb)` is the same as `mtcars %$% table(gear, carb)`, etc.

`plyr::ldply()` concatenates (`rbind`s) all the dataframes or matrices in a list. Since `map` returns a list of matrices, `ldply` is needed to combine all of them.

Finally, `cbind` attaches the accuracy measures back to the original table.

Comment: WOW. I don't know how you did that but it totally worked. AMAZING. I could not figure that out for like 2 days. THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Haha thanks for the feedback!! Glad I could help! I added some more details about the operators and functions I used. Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: Again, thank you Vlad. I'm going to have to these kinds of operations for months to support a project, so I'm very grateful that you helped me get through the learning curve. %$% and dplyr::ldply() are totally new to me and very helpful in my current project.